# How to overcome this java syntax so that double become string?

Tags: java, syntax, paypal

I am stuck in a situation whereby my Bean class - CartItemBean is in double.

```
    public double getTotalCost() {
    return dblTotalCost;
```

And the SetExpressCheckOutService class requires me to put the amount in String.

```
    String amount = "";
    CartItemBean details = new CartItemBean();
    amount = details.getTotalCost();

        try {
        //calling the service, setting up the checkoutpage
        String token = setExpressCheckoutService.setExpressCheckout(userId, amount, 
        currencyCode, returnURL, cancelURL, paymentAction);
        log.info("Url to redirect to: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com               
        /webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=" + token);
    } catch (PayPalException e) {

     // Log the exception

        log.log(Level.WARNING, "Paypal exception", e);

    }
     }
```

I hope someone can advise me how to overcome a problem like this.

Thanks.

Comment: see java.lang.String.valueOf(double d)

Answer (score 3):

Use the toString method of the Double object:

String string = Double.toString(double);

So in your code do this:

```
String token = setExpressCheckoutService.setExpressCheckout(userId, Double.toString(amount), currencyCode, returnURL, cancelURL, paymentAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

amount = **Double.toString**(details.getTotalCost());